# How to invoke an Android Intent that expects a result from Codename One Native Code

Tags: android, android-activity, codenameone

How do I replace Android code that uses the `onActivityResult` functionality of native Android programming within a Codename One [native class](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html).

I can invoke a standard `Activity` in the code using:

```
AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
```

And importing:

```
import com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil;
```

But how do I get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
AndroidNativeUtil.startActivityForResult(intent, new IntentResultListener() {
    public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         // your android native code here...
    }
});
```

Notice that your imports should now include:

```
import com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil;
import com.codename1.impl.android.IntentResultListener;
```